# Put 5 divs into 2 columns, 2 fixed on the left

Tags: html, css, css-float

Long challenge I have had, and I just need to ask for help now.

I have a container for divs:

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="1">Bla</div>
 <div id="2">Bla</div>
 <div id="3">Bla</div>
 <div id="4">Bla</div>
 <div id="5">Bla</div>
</div>
```

Now, div 1 and 2 should be fixed and floating on the left. Width 50%. All the other divs, should be on the right and just continue to float on the right no matter how long and how many divs I add. Width is also 50%.

Im thinking of something like this:

```
|--1--|--3--|
|--2--|--4--|
|-----|--5--|
|-----|--6--|
|-----|-----|
```

Any tips? I am just confused on relative and absolute and what is supposed to float where...

I should add, div 1 and 2 should be "scroll" fixed. So position: fixed. Its a bit how the facebook newsfeed is strcutured.

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Why not create 1 additional div for each left and right?

Comment: I want to run a script which can only edit the existing CSS - and thats the way the CSS is built out. Otherwise - yeah :)

Answer (score 1):

I think i solved your problems. You can use this code for your problem it may be help me.You can add many `div` in second column but you should use  this `width:50%; background:pink; float:left; margin-left:50%;` css code. You can change `background` according to you.

[Live Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/bzej4pL4/1/)

**HTML Code:**

```
 <div id="container">
 <div id="one">1</div>
 <div id="two">2</div>
 <div id="three">3</div>
 <div id="four">4</div>
 <div id="five">5</div>
 <div id="six">6</div>
 <div id="seven">7</div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
 #container
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#one
{
    width:50%;
    background:red;

}
#two
{
    width:50%;
    background:green;
    float:left;vertical-align:top;

}
#three
{
    width:50%;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    margin-top:-20px;
}
#four
{
    width:50%;
    background:gray;
    float:left;
    margin-left:50%;
    margin-top:-20px;

}
#five
{
    width:50%;
    background:violet;
    float:left;
    margin-left:50%;

}
#six
{
    width:50%;
    background:gold;
    float:left;
    margin-left:50%;

}
#seven
{
    width:50%;
    background:pink;
    float:left;
    margin-left:50%;

}
```

**Result:**

[image: Results]